# Error: The non-abstract class 'StethoHttpClientResponse' is missing implementations for these members: - HttpClientResponse.compressionState

Tags: flutter, dart

Compiler message:

```
 Error: The non-abstract class 'StethoHttpClientResponse' is missing implementations for these members:
 - HttpClientResponse.compressionState
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class StethoHttpClientResponse extends StreamView<List<int>>
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
org-dartlang-sdk:///third_party/dart/sdk/lib/_http/http.dart:2003:42: Context: 'HttpClientResponse.compressionState' is defined here.
  HttpClientResponseCompressionState get compressionState;
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: What part of that error message do you not understand? It even suggests the possible remedies.

Comment: So when i remove Stetho.initialize(); from the main func it's work but when i added it not workin for me 

void main() {
  Stetho.initialize();
  runApp(App());
}

Comment: Yes, if you don't create any object with that type, the fact that the type cannot be instantiated no longer matters. If you do want to create an object of that type, do one of the things suggested by the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter 1.22 breaks `flutter_stetho`, and this bug already fixed, but not approved by maintainer.

Use this unapproved version of `flutter_stetho`:

```
flutter_stetho:  
    git:
      url: git://github.com/jasonlewicki/flutter_stetho.git
      ref: master
```

More details here: https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_stetho/issues/39#issuecomment-695370252